# Unity Build Error: CS0103 and Missing Context for 'EditorUtility' and 'AssetDatabase

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, model

I would like to write a question on Stack Overflow to seek advice on a problem I encountered in Unity. My project involves the movement of a 3D tooth. In the project, we allow users who are dentists to import a CSV file containing the positions of each tooth. We then copy the file into our project folder. When the user clicks the "Next Week" button, the program should save the new tooth positions into a new CSV file with a name formatted as "Week + n" incrementally. The program should also retrieve the latest CSV file values to use in the next week. This allows the user to move the tooth according to their preference. Additionally, the user should be able to save and export the values as an STL file by clicking the "Save and Export" button.

However, when building the program for Windows, I encountered the following error:

UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 4 errors
at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x002da] in :0
at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00080] in :0
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)

error CS0103: The name 'EditorUtility' does not exist in the current context
error CS0103: The name 'AssetDatabase' does not exist in the current context
Build completed with a result of 'Failed' in 3 seconds (2931 ms)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)

Could you please assist me in resolving this issue?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/706O2.jpg)

```
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using CsvManagement;
using System.IO;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine.UI;

namespace Submit
{
    public class SubmitManager : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public GameObject teeth;
        public CsvExampleObjectSpawner csv = new CsvExampleObjectSpawner();
           
        public static int countweek;
        public static string filename;
        
        public void submit()
        {
            if(CsvExampleObjectSpawner.next == 1)
            {
                countweek = countweek + 1;
                filename = "week"+countweek+".csv";
                csv.wirteCSV(filename);     
                AssetDatabase.Refresh();
          

                //สร้าง Gameobject teeth ขึ้นมา 
                StartCoroutine(NextScenes());
            }

            else
            {
                Debug.Log("Please sellect file");
            }
            
            
        }


        IEnumerator NextScenes()
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);        
            SceneManager.LoadScene("Scene2");
                
        }
        
    }
}
```

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using LINQtoCSV;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using CsvManagement;


namespace CsvManagement
{

    public class CsvExampleObjectSpawner : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private Dictionary<string, GameObject> prefabs = new Dictionary<string, GameObject>();

        [Tooltip("The prefabs for each object")]
        public GameObject[] objects;
        public GameObject myGameObjects;

        [Tooltip("The file that contains the objects to be spawned in this scene")]
        public TextAsset sceneDescriptor;
        string sourcePath;
        public static string filename;
        public Text FileName;
       
        //Path of asset in the unity's project.
        public static Stack<string> stackOfFiles = new Stack<string>();
        public static int next; 

        public List<CsvSceneObject> posOfTeeth = new List<CsvSceneObject>();

       
        void Awake()
        {
            //Store object names(12 teeth) into arrays.
            foreach(var obj in objects)
            {
                prefabs[obj.name] = obj;
                
            }


        }
      

        public void OpenFileExplorer()
        {
            sourcePath = EditorUtility.OpenFilePanel("Select the CSV file", "", "csv");
        
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sourcePath))
            {
                filename = Path.GetFileName(sourcePath);
                FileName.text = "File Name : " +filename;
               
                CheckEmptyFolderAndAddFile();
                next = 1;
               
                
            }
            else
            {
                // User canceled the dialog
                if(stackOfFiles == null)
                {
                    next = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.Log("The user unselected the file.");
                }
                
                
            }
                
        }

        public void CheckEmptyFolderAndAddFile()
        {
            string path = "Assets/Resources/";
            
            //ไม่มีไฟล์อยู่ใน resources
            if (Directory.GetFiles(path).Length == 0 && Directory.GetDirectories(path).Length == 0)
            {
                Debug.Log("Directory is empty.");
                loadCSV();
                readCSV(filename, path);
                stackOfFiles.Push(filename); 
            }

            //มีไฟล์อยู่ใน resources
            else
            {          
                foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(path))
                {
                    File.Delete(file);
                    //AssetDatabase.Refresh();

                }

                //ใส่ไฟล์เข้าไปใน resources
                loadCSV();
                readCSV(filename, path);
                stackOfFiles.Push(filename);
                
            }
            
        }

    

        public void loadCSV()
        {
            string backupPath = Application.dataPath + "/Resources/";
            File.Copy(sourcePath, Path.Combine(backupPath, filename));
           // AssetDatabase.Refresh();
           
            
        }

        public void readCSV(string filename, string path)
        { 
            string pathOfFile = path + filename;
            sceneDescriptor = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath(pathOfFile, typeof(TextAsset)) as TextAsset;
            CsvFileDescription inputFileDescription = new CsvFileDescription
            {
                SeparatorChar = ',', 
                FirstLineHasColumnNames = true
            };

            using (var ms = new MemoryStream(sceneDescriptor.text.Length))
            {
                using (var txtWriter = new StreamWriter(ms))
                {
                    using (var txtReader = new StreamReader(ms))
                    {
                        txtWriter.Write(sceneDescriptor.text);
                        txtWriter.Flush();
                        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                        //Read CSV file
                        CsvContext cc = new CsvContext();
                        cc.Read<CsvSceneObject>(txtReader, inputFileDescription)
                            .ToList()
                            .ForEach( so =>
                            {
                                //Transform the position of 12 teeth.
                                myGameObjects = prefabs[so.PrefabName];
                                myGameObjects.transform.position = new Vector3(so.X, so.Y, so.Z);
                                myGameObjects.transform.Rotate(so.RoX, so.RoY, so.RoZ);
                                                        
                            });
                    }
                }
                
            }

            
        }

        public void wirteCSV(string filename)
        {
            string pathOfFile = "Assets/CsvWeek/" +filename;
            for(int i = 0; i < objects.Length; i++)
            {
                posOfTeeth.Add(
                    new CsvSceneObject
                    {
                        PrefabName = objects[i].name.ToString(),
                        X = objects[i].transform.position.x,
                        Y = objects[i].transform.position.y,
                        Z = objects[i].transform.position.z,
                        RoX = objects[i].transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x,
                        RoY = objects[i].transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y,
                        RoZ = objects[i].transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z


                    }
                );
       
                
            }
           
            CsvFileDescription outputFileDescription = new CsvFileDescription
            {
                SeparatorChar = ',', 
                FirstLineHasColumnNames = true,
            };


            CsvContext cc = new CsvContext();
            cc.Write<CsvSceneObject>(posOfTeeth, pathOfFile, outputFileDescription);

            Debug.Log("Successfully wrote the file.");
            
        
        }
     
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you reduce the amount of code in your question?

Answer (score 1):

You **cannot** use neither 'EditorUtility' nor 'AssetDatabase' in Unity Build.

You **can only** access these classes in Unity Editor. Furthermore you should put these scripts in 'Editor' Folder.

If you really need to access File Explorer here are some links (TL;DR):

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z1qT65GL-6Q
- https://answers.unity.com/questions/43422/how-to-implement-show-in-explorer.html

Answer (score 0):

[Filipeak answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76350386/21567154) is correct, but I'd like to nail down some details

**Why `UnityEditor` does not work on build**

When coding for Unity Editor alike solutions (such as tools, development assets, etc) we'll access "areas" of Unity that are not bundled with our game - for instance: there's no need for Unity to pack & compile all editor window modules with your game, since the end-user will not interact with this interface.

**Stripping code easily**

There are some ways to strip assets (or functions) when building withouth having to re-code or manually toggle class names:

1. **Using Folders** : There are some special folders structure to use when building with unity ([check this](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SpecialFolders.html)). As you'd like to get some code working only on editor, you may have to create all your classes inside "Editor" folder (note that all assets inside this **will not be available on build**)
2. **C# Technique - Script Definition Symbols** : You can define [scripting symbols](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CustomScriptingSymbols.html) so the [compiler will read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives) your code depending on that very block. You can use it to check `UNITY_EDITOR` symbol to whether toggle a code-block to run only when on Unity Editor

**Interacting with files/directories on-build**

You can interact with folders and user files while in build. To do it so, check the [System.IO namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io?view=net-7.0), which will include functions to aid on interacting with your user OS file-system - please keep in mind the different path/permissions patterns that you may use when targeting different platforms